# Вывести четное число из последовательности включая 0

Tags: android

Подскажите, как реализовать решение. Аргумент функции номер от 1 до п. При вводе номера нужно чтобы из последовательности возвращалось четное число, которое находится в ней под введенным номером. Например ввод 1 - возврат 0, ввод 2 - возврат 2, ввод 3 - возврат 4, ввод 4 - возврат 6 и тд

Comment: а откуда последовательно сть берется?

Comment: Последовательности нет, есть только вводимый аргумент из последовательности

Comment: __При вводе номера нужно чтобы из последовательности возвращалось четное число, которое находится в ней под введенным номером.__ если последовательность неизвестна, как найти в ней число на некой позиции?!

Comment: `System.out.println(n * 2 - 2);` ???

Comment: Значить это последовательность должна быть создана во время выполнения кода, а из нее вернуть четное число под нужным номером

Comment: а в чем тогда вопрос? ну обратитесь по индексу, верните число...

Comment: Я вам намекаю, что тут кроме "спасибо без масла", вопрос "принимают" и если нравится ставят "палец вверх"

Answer (score 0):

```
int foo(int n) {
    return (n - 1) * 2;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Очень простецкое решение оказалось, а я промучился полдня